# Want to make border color red when input is invalid

Tags: angular

I now have a text appear that says the input is invalid, but I would like to make the border red instead of displaying this text, because it looks pretty sloppy. I wondered how I can do this, can't seem to find a right solution online.

This is the code at the moment:

```
 <input placeholder="Vraag" formControlName="actualQuestion" type="text" class="form-control">
                        <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="isSubmitted && formControls.actualQuestion.errors?.required"> This field is required. </div>
                        <input placeholder="Optie 1" formControlName="option1" type="text" class="form-control">
                        <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="isSubmitted && formControls.option1.errors?.required"> This field is required. </div>
                        <input placeholder="Optie 2" formControlName="option2" type="text" class="form-control">
                        <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="isSubmitted && formControls.option2.errors?.required"> This field is required. </div>
```

I uploaded an image with a drawn border around "Optie 1" to clarify what I mean.
[image]

Comment: Do you use reactive forms or template driven forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the error state by:

By styling your error state you can set an ngClass which takes an expression to set the class:

`formControls.controls.option1.isValid`

Apply this boolean to your selector:

`<input [ngClass]="{'input-error': formControls.controls.option1.isValid} placeholder="Optie 1" formControlName="option1" type="text" class="form-control">`

In your .scss/.css you can then apply your styles to the class `.input-error` like:

```
.input-error {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Angular make it for you. Angular add the class ng-invalid and ng-touched. see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes. The correct answer is Sven Jäger or Chellappan

Answer (score 7):

You could also just add in you css-file this pointer:

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular append many control properties onto the form control element as CSS [classes](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes).

So you can use the .ng-valid and .ng-invalid classes to set the color of each form control's border.

```
.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
  border: 2px solid red /* red */
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyjpem)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use angular ng-style or ng-class directive and when there you can use your validation. if its true  (you have an error), border-color will bed set to red, else grey or none or whatever :d

```
[ngStyle]="{'border-color': form.hasError['required'] ? 'red' : 'grey'}"
```

something like that could work

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `.invalid` class when validation fails.

```
.invalid {
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
<input placeholder="Vraag" formControlName="actualQuestion" type="text" class="form-control" [class.invalid]="isSubmitted && formControls.actualQuestion.errors?.required">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="
                                            formFieldCss(
                                                form_Need,
                                                formSubmitAttempt,
                                                'zipcode'
                                            )
                                        ">
                                        <label>Zip Code
                                            <i class="text-danger" *ngIf="!isViewFlag">*</i></label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipcode" formControlName="zipcode" numbersOnly
                                            maxlength="5" />
                                        <span *ngIf="
                                                form_Need.get('zipcode').hasError('required') &&
                                                form_Need.get('zipcode').touched
                                            " class="help-block">This field is required</span>
                                        <span *ngIf="
                                                form_Need.get('zipcode').hasError('whitespace') &&
                                                !form_Need.get('zipcode').hasError('required') &&
                                                form_Need.get('zipcode').touched
                                            " class="help-block">This field is required</span>
                                    </div>
```

call this function

```
formFieldCss(form, formSubmitAttempt, field: string) {
    return {
        'has-error': this.formFieldValid(form, formSubmitAttempt, field),
        'has-feedback': this.formFieldValid(form, formSubmitAttempt, field)
    }
}


formFieldValid(form, formSubmitAttempt, field: string) {

    return (
        (!form.get(field).valid && form.get(field).touched) ||
        (form.get(field).untouched && formSubmitAttempt)
    )
}

formValid(form) {
    return form.invalid;
}
```

Comment: Calling functions in the template is really bad practice (besides user interactions) since it takes more processing power instead of just putting a primitive value.

Answer (score 0):

It can done by using **ngClass** directive as follow:

```
<input type="email" class="input" [ngClass]="{'red-border-class': submitted && formControl.email.errors}" id="inputEmail" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter Email">


.red-border-class { border: red 1px solid;}
```